# cartojs 4 and print button

Tags: leaflet, carto, printing, plugins

Is it possible to use the print function of leaflet with cartojs v.4?

i'm not able to use all this plugins 
https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport

The print button works but can i use also all other plugins of leaflet?

for example i'm tryng to use ruler plugin (https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler) but i've
Uncaught TypeError: 
L.control.ruler is not a function

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)! When you have a chance, please edit your question to include what happens when you try to use the plugin you referenced - do you receive an error? Does the plugin not install at all?  Have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way is to use airship and adding a button in the header section

```
<header class="as-toolbar">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
</header>
```